# Batch Insert the line number in each line

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have a little problem and can not get on right now.
I would like to batch import a .txt file and output this with line numbers to another .txt.
For example, the test.txt file looks like this:

```
hello
how 
are 
you
```

The result should be the file test2.txt and look like this:

```
1: hello
2: how
3: are
4: you
```

I have tried the following batch but unfortunately I only get an empty file as output:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
findstr / n; test.txt >test2.txt
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it is possible in the original file, but in a new one would be ok too.

Comment: Ok, well I posted both options, the second one is the one you want to use seeing as original is the prefered.

Comment: Without a space trailing the line number,colon `findstr /n "^" test.txt >test2.txt` Findstr needs a match, here the begin of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version will do write from `test.txt` to `test2.txt`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "myfile=test.txt"
set "outputfile=test2.txt"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%myfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%myfile%"') do (
     set "str=%%a
     set "str=!str:]=: !"
     set "str=!str:[=!"
     >>%outputfile% echo(!str!
  )
```

This version will write back to the original file, `test.txt` and write back to `test.txt`, thus overwriting it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "myfile=test.txt"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%myfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%myfile%"') do (
     set "str=%%a
     set "str=!str:]=: !"
     set "str=!str:[=!"
     >>%myfile% echo(!str!
  )
```

Which will do what you want:

```
1: hello
2: how 
3: are 
4: you
```

**Note**, this will also number `\n` in other words new empty lines. So for instance, if you have:

```
hello

how 
are 
you
```

It will result in:

```
1: hello
2:
3: how 
4: are 
5: you
```

Comment: Using `FIND` will work until they have brackets in their data. At which point the data will be corrupted.  `FINDSTR` uses a colon as the separator so that seems like it would be the better option.

Comment: a side note `>"%output%" ( for…( code here ) )` will open file only once, improving performance a lot, think about a large file

Comment: @elzooilogico. Yes. But i once encountered an issue when writing back to file. But cannot remember what is was but will have to test again to try and get error to reoccur ao I can show what it is.

Comment: I only can think when overwriting the source file. cannot test as I'm on mobile

Comment: `type "%myfile%" ^| find /v /n ""` could be shortened to `^< "%myfile%" find /v /n ""`. To avoid having to remove `[` by sub-string replacement you could just change `tokens=*` to `tokens=* delims=[`...

Comment: @elzooilogico I remember now, when writing back to the original file, the file is open for reading and we get the _"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"_ error.

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard thanks for the follow up, it's what I supposed

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to use `findstr`, like this:

```cmd
findstr /N "^" "test.txt" > "test_NEW.txt"
```

The above command line regards empty lines. To ignore and remove them, do this:

```cmd
findstr /N /V "^$" "test.txt" > "test_NEW.txt"
```

To replace your original file just execute the following afterwards:

```cmd
move /Y "test_NEW.txt" "test.txt" > nul
```

Regard that there is *no*  <kbd>SPACE</kbd> inserted after the colon that follows the line number.